# How to have a perfect skyline using transform:skew?

Tags: css

I wonder if it is possible to have a perfect edge using transform:skew (I would like to attach an img but I cannot (1 point))

https://ibb.co/g5qODG (image example with out shadow. It still is looking bitten.)

At the moment it looks like bit bitten as it was a low resolution image

Please find below an extract of my current HTML.

```css
/***UPS***/

.ups-container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ups-container h4 {
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  min-height: 76px;
}

.ups-container p {
  color: #c5b7d9;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

.ups-container strong {
  color: #fff;
}

.skew:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10vh;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #360d97;
  background-image: url("https://static.contrado.com/resources/images/2017-9/69479/bg-words-174927.png");
  background-image: url("https://static.contrado.com/resources/images/2017-9/69479/bg-words-174927.png"), linear-gradient(213deg, #360d97 42%, #79149e 89%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left bottom;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: initial;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 -10px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 -4px 14px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-no-inner">
  <div class="ups-container">
    <div class="skew">
      <div class="row center-xxs ups-line-up ">

        Hola!

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of using `backface-visibility: initial`, try `backface-visibility: hidden`. That should turn on compositing and will make the browser perform anti-aliasing a lot better.

Comment: @Terry Thank you it looks much better now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the problem of the resolution is done due to box-shadow. I just removed it and it looks fine. I think you have to start with this and if you need the shadow just add new html tags and style them to get your designed feature:

```css
/***UPS***/

.ups-container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ups-container h4 {
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  min-height: 76px;
}

.ups-container p {
  color: #c5b7d9;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

.ups-container strong {
  color: #fff;
}

.skew:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -26px;
  width: 110%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #360d97;
  transform: skew(0,-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-no-inner">
  <div class="ups-container">
    <div class="skew">
      <div class="row center-xxs ups-line-up ">

        Hola!

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hello 

It looks much better. However, it doesn't look perfect yet, like just a solid diagonal line without any bite. Is it not possible to achieve a perfect line with transfome:skew? Because my client is complaining about this detail.

Comment: may be you can have a look at this page I did 3 years ago: https://www.1and1.com/. We brought 2 weeks to get these skews working fine. May be you can use dev tools and have a look at it